# I need help creating a program in c that prints average and count of user inputed values

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point, average

This program must fill a constant array of doubles with user inputs. It must keep count of all digits excluding chars when they are input. 0s count. After compilation it will accept inputs but the program immediately terminates. Right now it will only output the average but the count should be tracked as of now. I'm unfamiliar with c so any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 1000

double avgNoZero(double array[], int size);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    double array[SIZE];
    double number;
    double average;
    int count = 0;

    while (scanf("%lf", & number == 1) && (count < SIZE)) { //I'm receving warnings about number being an int
        array[count++] = number;
    }
    average = avgNoZero(array, count); 
    printf("%f\n", average);
    return 0;
}
double avgNoZero(double array[], int size) {
int i; 
//int count = 0;
double sum = 0;

for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sum += array[i]; 
    /*if (array[count] != 0 ) { //I'm unsure where the part that checks for non zero should be.
        sum += array[i];
    } */
}
    return sum / size; 

}
```

Comment: Get yourself a good C book. E.g. [the classical one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) has plenty of examples from this vein.

Comment: try changing print to printf("average %f  count %d\n", average, count); the ++ part of array[count++] in the scanf from stdin while loop is actually incrementing the count variable for you already! I recommend "Learn C the Hard Way" for good C books. count++ is the same as count = count + 1; It is tricky because the count variable is also used to index into the double array named array. Don't be afraid to split code like that into many lines that make sense to you, it's just like math, no shame in explicitly calculating one thing at a time to avoid combining steps! Good luck don't give up!

Answer (score 1):

At least this one problem

```
// while (scanf("%lf", & number == 1) && (count < SIZE)) 
while (scanf("%lf", & number) == 1 && (count < SIZE))
```

---

Good that OP has some warnings enabled and reported them.

```
 I'm receving warnings about number being an int
```

Comment: BTW, makes more sense to test  `count < SIZE` before `scanf()`.